# What is best way to start and stop hadoop ecosystem, with command line?

Tags: hadoop

I see there are several ways we can start hadoop ecosystem,

1. `start-all.sh & stop-all.sh`
   Which say it's deprecated use start-dfs.sh & start-yarn.sh.
2. `start-dfs.sh, stop-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh, stop-yarn.sh`
3. `hadoop-daemon.sh namenode/datanode and yarn-deamon.sh resourcemanager`

EDIT: I think there has to be some specific use cases for each command.

Comment: See [this](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_3.html) too for CDH4 "*Running services: when starting, stopping and restarting CDH components, always use the service (8) command rather than running scripts in /etc/init.d directly. This is important because service sets the current working directory to / and removes most environment variables (passing only LANG and TERM) so as to create a predictable environment in which to administer the service*"

Comment: FYI As a newbie, on CDH5 and CentOS I can't even find the start*/stop*.sh scripts. Instead, the service command, through /etc/init.d/ (e.g., 'hadoop-hdfs-datanode'), calls hadoop-daemon.sh start/stop (located at /usr/lib/hadoop/sbin/ on my machine). So it looks like the depreciated scripts have now been completely removed?

Comment: Following up (why can't I edit?), from the source I see the start*/stop*.sh scripts, which eventually call hadoop-daemons.sh. start-all.sh just calls start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh. HTH other newbies.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**start-all.sh & stop-all.sh :** Used to start and stop hadoop daemons all at once. Issuing it on the master machine will start/stop the daemons on all the nodes of a cluster. Deprecated as you have already noticed.

**start-dfs.sh, stop-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh, stop-yarn.sh :** Same as above but start/stop HDFS and YARN daemons separately on all the nodes from the master machine. It is advisable to use these commands now over start-all.sh & stop-all.sh

**hadoop-daemon.sh namenode/datanode and yarn-deamon.sh resourcemanager :** To start individual daemons on an individual machine manually. You need to go to a particular node and issue these commands.

Use case : Suppose you have added a new DN to your cluster and you need to start the DN daemon only on this machine,

```
bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
```

**Note :** You should have ssh enabled if you want to start all the daemons on all the nodes from one machine.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: why `start-all` and `stop-all` are deprected?

Answer (score 8):

From Hadoop [page](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop),

```
start-all.sh
```

This will startup a Namenode, Datanode, Jobtracker and a Tasktracker on your machine.

```
start-dfs.sh
```

This will bring up HDFS with the Namenode running on the machine you ran the command on. On such a machine you would need `start-mapred.sh` to separately start the job tracker

`start-all.sh/stop-all.sh` has to be run on the *master node*

You would use `start-all.sh` on a **single node** cluster (i.e. where you would have all the services on the same node.The namenode is also the datanode and is the master node).

In **multi-node** setup,

You will use `start-all.sh` on the master node and would start what is necessary on the slaves as well.

Alternatively,

Use `start-dfs.sh` on the node you want the *Namenode* to run on. This will bring up *HDFS* with the *Namenode* running on the machine you ran the command on and *Datanodes* on the machines listed in the slaves file.

Use `start-mapred.sh` on the machine you plan to run the *Jobtracker* on. This will bring up the Map/Reduce cluster with Jobtracker running on the machine you ran the command on and *Tasktrackers* running on machines listed in the slaves file.

`hadoop-daemon.sh` as stated by Tariq is used on each individual node. The master node will not start the services on the slaves.In a single node setup this will act same as `start-all.sh`.In a multi-node setup you will have to access each node (master as well as slaves) and execute on each of them.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/facebook/hadoop-20/blob/master/bin/start-all.sh) `start-all.sh` it call *config* followed by *dfs* and *mapred*

Comment: Ya thats right..But what i am interested in is usecases for all different  commands.

Answer (score 2):

**Starting**

```
start-dfs.sh (starts the namenode and the datanode)
start-mapred.sh (starts the jobtracker and the tasktracker)
```

**Stopping**

```
stop-dfs.sh
stop-mapred.sh
```

Comment: I think you got it wrong i asked is what is the best way to start and usecase for that. What you mentioned even i know that...

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows machine, follow these steps:

1.) Go to the Hadoop setup directory

2.) Inside the `data/dfs` directory, delete all the contents present in `datanode` and `namenode` folders.

3.) Then, execute this command: `hdfs namenode -format`

4.) Next, navigate to the `sbin` directory, open the Command Prompt in Administrator mode from that path.

5.) Execute the below commands:

- `start-dfs.cmd`
- `start-yarn.cmd`

6.) Execute `jps` command, to list all the available Hadoop services. The typical output should look like this:

```
22224 Jps
26592 NodeManager
14436 DataNode
23112 ResourceManager
26312 NameNode
```

If any one of the above services is missing, that means Hadoop did NOT start properly.

Hope this helps!