# Hadoop namenode cant fire the datanode

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I have a multinode setup on separate machines the namenode cant fire the datanode and the task tracker, the namenode, secondary node , jobtracker works fine

the namenode machine named namenode@namenode IP 192.168.1.1
the datanode machine named datanode2@datanode2 IP 192.168.1.2

the ssh server is setup and the id_rsa.pub is copied to the datanode

but when applying the start-all.sh command
when firing the datanode it asks for a password for namenode@datanode2

when providing the password it say permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You need to have core-site.xml with your namenode address. This needs to be same across cluster.

```
<property>       
 <name>fs.default.name</name>       
 <value>hdfs://$namenode.full.hostname:8020</value>  
 <description>Enter your NameNode hostname</description>
</property>
```

You can use script to start individual demons . Follow [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569423/what-is-best-way-to-start-and-stop-hadoop-ecosystem).

Comment: in the slaves file on namenode I had 'datanode2', I changed it to 'datanode2@datanode2' now the datanode is up but still asks for passwords !

Comment: in the slaves file I should provide the name of the datanodes right ?
and in the masters file I should have the name of the secondary node, am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Change permissions for `.ssh` folder and `authorized_keys` file as follows:

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh
sudo chmod 640 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

or

```
sudo chmod 700 /home/hadoop/.ssh
sudo chmod 640 /home/hadoop/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Refer [this](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) for more details.

**UPDATE I:**

Try 600 instead of 640 like this:

```
sudo chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown 'hadoop' $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If this did not work,try this one:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoopusrname@HOSTNAME.local
```

Change `HOSTNAME` with you local hostname and `hadoopusrname` with your hadoop username.

Comment: in the slaves file on namenode I had 'datanode2', I changed it to 'datanode2@datanode2' now the datanode is up but still asks for passwords ! I did alll the steps on the link you provided and changed the permissions !